# Python requests library not sending correct params

Tags: python, python-requests

I am sending post request to an API. The API expects params in raw format.

```
headers = {"content-type" : "application/json"}
url = "http://test.web.com/web_api/CreateHeader"
params = {"param1" : "asd", "param2" : "asdd"}
r = requests.post(url, data = json.dumps(params), headers = headers, auth = HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
r.json()
```

Here the post requests returns fails. However, if I send the params like this:

```
params ="{\n   \"param1\" : \"asd\", \"param2\" : \"asdd\"\n}"
r = requests.post(url, data = params, headers = headers, auth = HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
```

It succeeds. Do you guys know what is happening here?

Comment: why are you sending the data as json, just send it as a dictionary. Just do `data=params` instead of `data = json.dumps(params)`

Comment: The api expects data in raw format. I sent it as a dictionary and it failed.

Comment: Thank you but No, that was just the mistake that I made while typing out the question.

Comment: Have you tried sending the data as json instead? `r = requests.post(url, json=params, headers=headers)` Also, what header are you putting on the request?

Comment: I just tried It did not work. My headers has content-type and authorization.

Comment: The content-type is important, can you put that in the question?

Comment: It's internal api that I cannot discuss about.

Comment: well without knowing what the server expects only you can answer your question

Comment: As I have no access to your API, I can only guess. Have you tried to send a "raw" json without line-breaks? Dump to console _precise_ "json" which is send by requests and try to find difference. May be API requires line breaks for parsing...

Answer (score -1):

From your description the API seems to expect the data as json, so

```
r = requests.post(url, json=params, headers=headers)
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried that but It still didn't work.